# UITableViewDropCoordinator drop(_:toRowAt:) doesn't perform animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop, ios11

I have a UITableView with a drop delegate (iOS 11). In my implementation of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    performDropWith coord: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
```

... I'm calling the coordinator's `drop(_:toRowAt:)`. According to Apple, this should cause the drag item preview to animate to cover the cell exactly. But nothing of the kind is happening; the drag item preview is just shrinking away in place, exactly as if I weren't calling `drop(_:toRowAt:)` at all.

Does this command actually *do* anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewDropCoordinator `drop(_:toRowAt:)` does actually work, but only under a very limited set of circumstances. Here's what you have to understand:

- `drop(_:toRowAt:)` must be called in the main part of your `performDropWith` implementation — not inside an asynchronous `loadObject` call. That's true of all the UITableViewDropCoordinator `drop` commands.
- `drop(_:toRowAt:)` works like this:

  1. First, it *snapshots* the cell at the given row.
  2. Then, it substitutes that snapshot as the drag item preview, and animates the snapshot to cover the cell at that row.

Thus, `drop(_:toRowAt:)` is useful only in a very limited set of circumstances. By the time you give this command, if the cell in question is to change its appearance as a result of the drop, the cell must *already have been reloaded* — because the snapshot will correspond to the state of the cell at the time the `drop` command is given, and you don't want the cell's *old* appearance to animate out of the preview.

For this reason, `drop(_:toRowAt:)` is not useful in connection with `loadObject`. (That's what a *placeholder* is for.) It's useful only during a local drag where you can pick up the data instantly from the drag item's `localObject`. And it's useful only during the simple situation where you drop *onto* an existing cell and *replace* it.

Example:

```
guard let s = item.localObject as? String else {return}
// ... update model using s ...
tableView.reloadRows(at: [ip], with: .none)
coordinator.drop(item, toRowAt: ip)
```

Note that I did *not* call `performBatchUpdates`. `drop(_:toRowAt:)` doesn't work in connection with `performBatchUpdates`, because the snapshot will be taken too soon. It works only in this very limited simple set of circumstances.

(In the WWDC video on this topic, Apple seems to imply that `drop(_:toRowAt:)` corresponds in some way to a drop intent of `. insertAtDestinationIndexPath`. But that's *not true*. You cannot drop a snapshot of the cell you are about to insert, because you haven't inserted it yet. Again, that's what a placeholder is for.)

Comment: For me, I found Apples documentation misleading as it suggests to use a "batch update to delete and then insert rows" then call drop(), however this doesn't animate properly as discussed. Instead, try calling reloadData() followed by drop()